# Selecting elements from an array based on a condition

Tags: python, numpy

This may be a simple question but, let us say that we have an array :

`a = [0,10,20]`

What is the simplest way to retrieve the least value which is greater than 0?. In this case, it would be 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you included Numpy in your tags, I'm assuming you're OK with a solution with Numpy?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,10,20])

np.min(a[a > 0])
```

> Out[1]: 10

Answer (score 3):

Or a `min` on generator:

```
min(x for x in a if x > 0)
```

**Example**:

```
a = [0,10,20]

print(min(x for x in a if x > 0))
# 10
```

Answer (score 3):

I can try like this without using numpy.

```
def findValue():
    a = [0,10,5,20]
    a.sort()
    noToCheck = 0
    for i in a:
        if i > noToCheck :
            print("Found value: ", i)
            break

findValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty

```
a = [0, 10, 20]


def find_lowest_num(a):
    lowest_num = None
    for element in a:
        if lowest_num is None and element > 0:
            lowest_num = element
        elif lowest_num is None and element == 0:
            pass
        else:
            if element < lowest_num and element > 0:
                lowest_num = element
    return lowest_num

print(find_lowest_num(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `min()` function with a key:

```
min(a, key=lambda x: float("inf") if x<=0 else x)
```